# How to hide a div when input radio radio selected javascript angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to hide a div when a radio button is selected.

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <input type="radio" name="service_option" ng-model="service_option" value="adhoc" id="service_option">Adhoc <br/>
     <input type="radio" name="service_option" ng-model="service_option" value="weekly" id="service_option">Weekly
     <div class="product-noselected-message" style="font-size: 10px; color: red">Please choose an option</div>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-3">
 <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="getReservationDetails('lg', packageSlot)"> Book Now </button>    
</div>
```

In my code, if a radio button is selected, I want the div class = product-noselected-message to be hidden.

This is wht i have on my javascript at the moment

```
$scope.getReservationDetails = function(size, packageSlot) {
      var service_option;
      if($('input[name=service_option]:checked')) {

        service_option = $('input[name=service_option]:checked').val();
      }

      if (service_option!= null) {
        $rootScope.date = new Date();
        console.log($rootScope.date);
        $rootScope.singlePackageSlot = packageSlot;
        $rootScope.locationName = $scope.cleaningServiceLocation.name;

        modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'views/cleaning_services/register_event.html',
          controller: 'CleaningServicesCancelCtrl',
          size: size
        });
      }
      else {
        $('.product-noselected-message').html('Please select an option');
      }
    $('#service_option').on('checked', function() {
          $('.product-noselected-message').addClass('hidden');
        });
```

But it is not working wht do i do?

http://plnkr.co/edit/GVYuI47TKlAVqkVDUDOq

Comment: Added bootstrap as a tag, since Kingsley Simon did not care to add it, yet expected one of the answerers to guess that.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding `class="hidden"` to an HTML element does nothing at all, you need to accompany it with some CSS like

```
.hidden
{
    display: none; /* This will act like the element doesn't exist */
}
```

or

```
.hidden
{
    visibility: hidden; /* The element will be 100% transparent, but still take up space */
}
```

depending on your exact goals.

Comment: just adding hidden when u have twitter bootstrap.css in ur main html works. sorry but your answer is 100% wrong.

Comment: @KingsleySimon, may I ask you where did you specify you are using bootstrap.css? I am sorry, but your arrogant and unreasonable comment reduced my motivation to help you to 0. Upvote to support an accurate answer in view of the available information.

Comment: @LajosArpad well thanks for ur comment. but it has been added in my other pages. i didnt think i had to add my entire code in here. well if it reduced ur motivation thts fine maybe someone else will feel motivated to help me. cheers

Comment: Very simple: you can add a tag there. You should be nicer to people trying to help you. They are working for you for free, out of goodwill. They deserve respect when they ask the question (by adding bootstrap tag, for example) and respect in comments (if you point out an inaccuracy, you can do it in a civilized, non-arrogant way as well).

Comment: thnks and apologies to @siguza. thnks Lajos Arpad.

Answer (score 0):

add NG-IF on div, and check for "service_option" not null 
add `ng-if="!service_option"`  on 'product-noselected-message' div, you dont need css class to hide and show div in angularJS, make use of [NG-IF](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) or [NG-SHOW](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) or [NG-HIDE](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)

```
<div class="col-md-3">
 <input type="radio" name="service_option" ng-model="service_option" value="adhoc" id="service_option">Adhoc <br/>
 <input type="radio" name="service_option" ng-model="service_option" value="weekly" id="service_option">Weekly
<div ng-if="!service_option" class="product-noselected-message" style="font-size: 10px; color: red">Please choose an option</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have edited my code for input. i dont want the div to be visible upon initial load. It only becomes visible if the button is clicked and there is no selected radio button but when a radio button is selected, then it hides the div

Comment: @KingsleySimon quick n dirty way add isFormSubmitted flag on scope and change  ng-if  condition to  ng-if="isFormSubmitted && !service_option "

Answer (score 0):

Just like BeingDev said, ng-if/ng-show/ng-hide is the angular way of doing..

Below is a plunker link in which you can check the output

http://plnkr.co/edit/GVYuI47TKlAVqkVDUDOq?p=preview

```
 <div ng-hide="service_option" class="product-noselected-message" style="font-size: 10px; color: red">Please choose an option</div>
```

Comment: not denying that BeingDev option works but i dont want the div to be visible upon initial load. It shud only be visible when the button is clicked

Comment: the trigger to show the "please choose an option" is a button so it is not to be shown upon initial load. It only shows when the button is clicked and no radio button has been selected. But upon any radio button selected, it hides the div if it is visible

Comment: Here we are adding a watch event to hide the visible message on clicking of radio  http://plnkr.co/edit/GVYuI47TKlAVqkVDUDOq?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to go here, some better depending in your full code but I'll go with what you requested, exactly.

That's a job for ng-class, which will assign a class name if a condition is evaluated as true:

```
  <div ng-class="{'hidden' : service_option != '' && other_option }" ...
```

What you need to know is that the class name in single quotes above, will be assigned to the div (or any element) if the condition on the right evaluates to true. In this case, an value selected in the radios will stop service_option from being an empty string. Could be whatever you might need, ofcourse.

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("mycontroller", function($scope) {
  $scope.service_option = "";

})
```

```css
.hidden {display:none;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.6" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myapp">
    <div class="col-md-3" ng-controller="mycontroller">
      <input type="radio" name="service_option" ng-model="service_option" value="adhoc" id="service_option" />
Adhoc
          <br />
      <input type="radio" name="service_option" ng-model="service_option" value="weekly" id="service_option" />
Weekly
      <div ng-class="{'hidden' : service_option != '' }" class="product-noselected-message" style="font-size: 10px; color: red">Please choose an option</div>

  <p>Value Selected : {{service_option}}</p>
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

EDIT
According to your latest comment below, you need to assign a class after evaluating two things. So:

```
  <div ng-class="{'hidden' : service_option != '' || other_option }" class="product-noselected-message" style="font-size: 10px; color: red">Please choose an option</div>
```

this would do it. Here is a plunker link so that it dont gets confused with the code above:

http://plnkr.co/edit/pYpKwagYmYTxURM1aJft?p=preview

Comment: the trigger to show thew "please choose an option" is a button so it is not to be shown upon initial load. It only shows when the button is clicked and no radio button has been selected. But upon any radio button selected, it hides the div if it is visible